# How do I simulate 20000 user logins in a load test of an azure hosted webapp?

Tags: visual-studio, azure, load-testing, adfs

I have a client who wants me to do a load test of their azure hosted webapp.  They want to test the login mechanism for 1000, 5000, 10,000, and finally 20,000 concurrent users.  They want to use ADFS logins for the webapp.

They're a touch reluctant to create 20,000 AD users on their side and to let me use the login details for my test.  They say they'll supply me with 10 users.

I'm going to be using the visual studio online load testing utility for my actual load test.

Is there any value in just spawning the same 10 users in 100(and eventually 2000) different threads and logging in that way?

Do I need them to give me a new OU with 20,000 users in it?

Comment: Use this calculator to determine the number of rows required for your test. http://www.webperformance.com/library/tutorials/CalculateNumberOfLoadtestUsers/